# C# getting full path of an input file in win XP

Tags: c#

I wrote a simple console tool that reads a file and then writes something out. I intend to just drag and drop files and then out pops the output in the same directory as the input file.

All of the testing works, and when I call it from command-line, everything comes out as expected. However, when I tried dragging and dropping it in explorer, no files were created.

I did a search through the system and found that they were all dumped at Documents and Settings under my user folder, and when I printed out the full path that's what it said.

Which is weird. Wouldn't `Path.GetFullPath` return the absolute path of the input file? Instead it looks like it just combined that user directory path to the input's filename.

EDIT: here's the code. I feel like I've made a logic error somewhere but can't seem to see it.

```
filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(args[i]);
abspath = Path.GetFullPath(filename);
dirpath = Path.GetDirectoryName(abspath);
....
Console.WriteLine(dirpath);
```

Comment: You'll need to post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Path.GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) should return the absolute path of the path string you pass in.

[Path.GetFileName(string path)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) only returns the filename and extension of the file you pass in.  For example, `System.IO.Path.GetFileName("C:\SomeDirectory\Test.txt");` would just return "Test.txt".  You'll want to use the [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname) to get the path of your input file, like so:

```
string inputDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(args[i]);
```

Alternately, you can use the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class to retrieve a bunch more information about your input file.  For example:

```
// Assuming args[i] = "C:\SomeDirectory\Test.txt"
FileInfo inputFile = new FileInfo(args[i]);
string inputDirectory = inputFile.DirectoryName; // "C:\SomeDirectory"
string inputFileName = inputFile.Name; // "Test.txt"
string fullInputFile = inputFile.FullName; // "C:\SomeDirectory\Test.txt"
```

Comment: Oh, I see where I made a mistake.